# How to destructuring this kind of nested Objects?

Tags: node.js, typescript, azure, object, nested-object

Following a request on the Microsoft Azure API translator, I get a list of languages as nested objects. I would like to recover only some values like the "language code and name, but I can't destructure the objects. If you have ideas, methods to advise me, I am really interested.
Thank you very much. Thank you very much.

I have tried to destroy nested objects but I can't.

```
async getAzureLanguages() {
    const getLanguages: any = await new AzureLanguageApi().supportedLanguages();
    let provider: string = `Microsoft`;
    const languages: ILanguages[] = [{ code: ``, name: ``, providers: [``] }];
    const azureLanguageKeys: any = Object.keys(getLanguages.translation);
    const azureLanguageValues: any = Object.values(getLanguages.translation);
    azureLanguageValues.forEach((element: { code: string; name: string }) => {
                return languages.push({code: '', name: element.name, providers: [provider]})
            })
            // console.log('languages :', languages);
            return getLanguages;
}
```

Here is the first result of the api request :

```
{"translation":{"af":{"name":"Afrikaans","nativeName":"Afrikaans","dir":"ltr"},"ar":{"name":"Arabic","nativeName":"العربية","dir":"rtl"},"bg":{"name":"Bulgarian","nativeName":"Български","dir":"ltr"},"bn":{"name":"Bangla","nativeName":"বাংলা","dir":"ltr"},"bs":{"name":"Bosnian","nativeName":"bosanski (latinica)","dir":"ltr"},"ca":{"name":"Catalan","nativeName":"Català","dir":"ltr"},"cs":{"name":"Czech","nativeName":"Čeština","dir":"ltr"},"cy":{"name":"Welsh","nativeName":"Welsh","dir":"ltr"},"da":{"name":"Danish","nativeName":"Dansk","dir":"ltr"},...
```

And my actual result :

`````
languages : [ { code: '', name: '', providers: [ '' ] },
  { code: '', name: 'Afrikaans', providers: [ 'Microsoft' ] },
  { code: '', name: 'Arabic', providers: [ 'Microsoft' ] },
  { code: '', name: 'Bulgarian', providers: [ 'Microsoft' ] },
  { code: '', name: 'Bangla', providers: [ 'Microsoft' ] },
  { code: '', name: 'Bosnian', providers: [ 'Microsoft' ] },
  { code: '', name: 'Catalan', providers: [ 'Microsoft' ] },...
````
I expect to have this :
````
languages : [ { code: 'af', name: 'Afrikaans', providers: [ 'Microsoft' ] },
  { code: 'ar', name: 'Arabic', providers: [ 'Microsoft' ] },
  { code: 'bg', name: 'Bulgarian', providers: [ 'Microsoft' ] },
  { code: 'bn', name: 'Bangla', providers: [ 'Microsoft' ] },
  { code: 'bs', name: 'Bosnian', providers: [ 'Microsoft' ] },
  { code: 'ca', name: 'Catalan', providers: [ 'Microsoft' ] },...
`````

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to do what you are trying to do:

```js
...
azureLanguageKeys.foreach(key => {
  languages.push({
    code: key, 
    name: getLanguages.translation[key].name, 
    providers: [provider]
  });
})
```

Or a for..in loop:

```js
...
for(const key in getLanguages.translation){
  languages.push({
    code: key, 
    name: getLanguages.translation[key].name, 
    providers: [provider]
  });
}
```

Also, you're initializing the languages array with the blank object. Initialize it this way:

```js
const languages: ILanguages[] = [];
```

Comment: Thank you very much Felix, I have exactly the expected result.